# Having problem using Jsoup to scrape website Data

Tags: java, jsoup

This is the html code for the website:

```
 <div class="list_item">
<a href="/p/fifa-19-ps4" title="Fifa 19... on PS4">
<img src="/uploads/products/42376/42376_xsm.jpg?v=MjAxOS0xMS0yNCAxNToxMjowMw==" alt="Fifa 19... on PS4" title="Fifa 19... on PS4" border="0">
<div class="product_name">Fifa 19...</div>
<span>£9.99</span>
</a>
<a href="/p/fifa-19-ps4" class="button in_stock" title="Fifa 19 on PS4">View Product</a>
</div>
```

My code using JSoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.simplygames.com/search?keywords=" + itemName).get();
    //Get all products on the page
    Elements products = doc.select("list_item");

    //work through the products using for loop
    for(int i = 0; i<products.size(); ++i){

    //get the product description
    Elements description = products.get(i).select("product_name");

    //get the products price
    Elements price = products.get(i).select("");

    //Ouput web scraped data
        System.out.println("DESCRIPTION: " + description.text() + "; PRICE:  " + price.text());


    }
```

I am having problem scraping the price from span element which has no class like div. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a similar thing to what you did to select the classes. Using .get on an Elements object that was created with .select() is giving you a list of all of the Element with that name.

For example,

```
Elements description = products.get(i).select("product_name");
```

This line gives you all of the `Element` on the page that has the class name "product_name"

What you want to do is run another select on each Element within the "product_name" group.

```
for (Element e : description) {
    String desc = e.ownText();
    String price = e.selectFirst("span").text();
}
```

Comment: Hey, there is a problem with description variable using String so if I do String description I get an error saying variable is already defined in method.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize I had used description twice. just switch the second description variable to any other variable name and it will work. I will edit my post to fix